# Serializing derived types - not in an array

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

Using the .NET XmlSerializer via the Visual Studio settings designer (auto-generated code), it is possible to serialize an array of derived types like this:

```
[XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(Square)), XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(Triangle))]
public Shape[] Shapes;

...

Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

and this produces XML like

```
<Shape>
  <Triangle>....</Triangle>
  <Triangle>....</Triangle>
  <Square>....</Square>
</Shape>
```

But what if the derived type isn't in an array (or any other collection)?

Replacing `XmlArrayItem` with `XmlElement`, the following

```
[XmlElement(Type = typeof(Square)), XmlElement(Type = typeof(Triangle))]
public Shape Window;
```

works but produces

```
<Triangle>....</Triangle>
```

where the element name is the type, not the property name, and if I add a second Shape:

```
[XmlElement(Type = typeof(Square)), XmlElement(Type = typeof(Triangle))]
public Shape Door;
[XmlElement(Type = typeof(Square)), XmlElement(Type = typeof(Triangle))]
public Shape Window;
```

serialization just fails - after all, how would it know on deserialization which XML element goes into which property?

Is there an attribute I'm missing? Can I make this work without writing code to customise the serialization? How?

Comment: The serializer only produces output one way with no options.  If you want different type output then you have to generate the xml using other net library methods.

Comment: The issue they are asking is about one class inheriting another class.  The serializer add an attribute type to the xml.  They wan the inherited type to be an element name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding [`[XmlInclude]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute.aspx) attributes on the root object as indicated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39916929/3744182) is a good solution as it handles all occurrences of polymorphic properties of type `Square` anywhere in the data model.

Nevertheless this situation can also be handled using [`[XmlElement]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx) attributes by disambiguating the polymorphic elements via [`XmlElementAttribute.ElementName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.elementname.aspx):

```
public class Room
{
    [XmlElement("DoorSquare", Type = typeof(Square)), XmlElement("DoorTriangle", Type = typeof(Triangle))]  
    public Shape Door { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("WindowSquare", Type = typeof(Square)), XmlElement("WindowTriangle", Type = typeof(Triangle))]  
    public Shape Window { get; set; }
}
```

This produces the following XML:

```
<Room>
  <DoorTriangle />
  <WindowSquare />
</Room>
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gkKeNy).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to use `XmlInclude` on the base class instead of `XmlElement` on the properties:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Triangle))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Square))]
public abstract class Shape
```

This generates slightly different XML. For the array case:

```
<Shapes>
  <Shape xsi:type="Triangle">....</Shape>
  <Shape xsi:type="Triangle">....</Shape>
  <Shape xsi:type="Square">....</Shape>
</Shapes>
```

and for the scalar case:

```
<Door xsi:type="Square">....</Door>
<Window xsi:type="Triangle">....</Window>
```

Perfect.

Answer (score -1):

A first draft at composite shape serialization:

```
  [Serializable()]
  [XmlRoot("shape", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
  public abstract class Shape {
    public abstract void Draw();
    [XmlAttribute("name")] public string Name { get; set; }
  }

  [Serializable()]
  [XmlRoot("triangle", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
  public class Triangle : Shape {
    public override void Draw() { }
  }

  [Serializable()]
  [XmlRoot("square", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
  public class Square : Shape {
    public override void Draw() { }
  }

  [Serializable()]
  [XmlRoot("compositeShape", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
  public class CompositeShape : Shape {
    [XmlElement("shape", typeof(Shape))]
    [XmlElement("triangle", typeof(Triangle))]
    [XmlElement("square", typeof(Square))]
    [XmlElement("compositeShape", typeof(CompositeShape))]
    public Shape[] Items { get; set; }

    public override void Draw() { }
  }
```

Use it like:

```
var shape = new CompositeShape() {
    Name = "some composite shape",
    Items = new Shape[] {
      new CompositeShape() { 
        Name = "inner composite shape",
        Items = new Shape[] {
          new Triangle() {Name = "level 2 triangle"},
          new Square() {Name="level 2 square"}
        } }, 
        new Triangle() {Name = "level 1 triangle"},
        new Square() {Name="level 1 square"}
    }};
    // serialize ...
```

Sample output:

```
<compositeShape name="some composite shape">
  <compositeShape name="inner composite shape">
    <triangle name="level 2 triangle" />
    <square name="level 2 square" />
  </compositeShape>
  <triangle name="level 1 triangle" />
  <square name="level 1 square" />
</compositeShape>
```

The downside with this approach is that every time you add an object to your hierarchy you also have to decorate the shape array with an element of that type, so not really closed for modification ...

Comment: That's an array of Shape objects. My question is specifically about the case where it is *not* in an array.

Comment: Then it is a shape that's not a composite, triangle or square